# Monoid morphisms satisfying a decomposition condition

Tags: reference-request, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $A$ and $B$ be monoids, let $f\colon A\to B$ be a morphism of monoids. The following pair of conditions emerged naturally in my research:

1. For all $a\in A$ and $b_1,b_2\in B$ such that $f(a)=b_1.b_2$ there are $a_1,a_2\in A$ such that $f(a_1)=b_1$, $f(a_2)=b_2$ and $a=a_1.a_2$.
2. If $f(a)=1$, then $a=1$.

Let me point out one elementary example to motivate the whole thing.

**Example** Let $K$ be a field, let $K_m$ be the multiplicative monoid of [monic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) over $K$. Then the mapping $d\colon K_m\to\mathbb{N}$ that takes a polynomial to its degree is a morphism of monoids (here, $\mathbb N$ is equipped with $+$, of course).

Now, $d$ satisfies the conditions 1. and 2. if and only if $K$ is algebraically closed.

There are several examples similar to that one: roughly speaking, $A$ contains some things, $B$ is commutative and $f$ means something like "measure/dimension/size" of the things from $A$ valued in $B$. If we allow $A$ to be a *partial* monoid, the number of interesting examples increases considerably.

**Question 1** Was condition 1. used by somebody in the past, within the context of monoids (or semigroups) ?

**Question 2** (soft version of Q1) Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that instead of 2. we assume:

2'. If $f(a)=b_1 b_2$ has two preimage factorizations $a=a_1 a_2 = a'_1 a'_2$, then there is some element $u \in A$ such that $f(u)=1$, $u a'_2 = a_2$ and $a_1 u = a'_1$.

Then this is the notion of a [Conduché functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Conduch%C3%A9+functor) applied to categories with one object.